# I want to halt VBA code to do some manual action while importing data?

Tags: excel, vba, validation, scrape

How do I halt a VBA macro to insert headers manually in different sheets, converted from text files, and then process them further with analysis?

Comment: Please include the code you have. [Without code, it is very hard to help you](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/).

Comment: There is no way to halt VBA, and if there was one, how should the VBA runtime know when to continue. You simply need to split your code into two procedures. When the manual work is done, you need to trigger the second routine. Trigger could be a button, a keyboard shortcut, or you could catch events (change, doubleclick...) on the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Create two functions and two buttons. The first button won't be enabled unless the first one was clicked on.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Me.CommandButton1.Enabled = False
End Sub

Function Button1_Click()
    'Do work.
    `Stop.
    Me.CommandButton1.Enabled = True
End Function

Function Button2_Click()
    'Continue.
End Function
```